# ConstraintLayout within ScrollView not Scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a screen with a title, 5 TextViews, 5 Spinners, and 2 buttons at the bottom which causes the 5th set of TextView/Spinner to go off-screen towards the bottom. I have searched about having a ScrollView within a ConstraintLayout and have tried the various things ive found with setting the certain height and width to "0dp" and adding the constraint to the ScrollView itself but still the only thing that happens is the 5 sets appear but still are not scrollable. I saw a question similar to this but they have nothing at the bottom so they constraint to the bottom of parent. I need to constraint to the top of my buttons at the bottom so my buttons stay in place and only the middle scrolls but when i set my bottom constraint to the top of buttons the entire view disappears.

This is my current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="teamtriplej.com.lipidlator21.CardiolipinsActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/Submit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.761"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/Back"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.216"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="@string/CLConfiguration"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Ion"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnIon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:entries="@array/ion_array"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvIon"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAcylChain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/sn1_1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnIon"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:entries="@array/sn_array"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAcylChain"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn1_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/sn1_3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnSn1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSn1_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:entries="@array/ratios_array"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn1_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_1_Result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/sn2_1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnSn1_3"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSn2_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:entries="@array/ratios_array"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn2_1_Result" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSn2_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sn2_3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnSn2_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSn2_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/ratios_array"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSn2_3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Because a screen can lay down all View,you can set one of View 's `android:layout_height="500dp"` .You will scroll in the screen.

Comment: So i should set the `android:layout_height="500dp"` inside the Scrollview instead of the wrap_content?

Comment: You could set the height of `TextView` or `Spinner` inside `ConstraintLayout` .And it will scroll.I try it in my code .And it worked .

Comment: Ok perfect I simply made all my spinners a little bit taller and it works but now I have a new issue... the scrollview still does not stop before reaching the buttons at the bottom... it scrolls behind the buttons

Comment: You want to ScrollView above the `Button(submit)` and `Button(back)` .

Comment: Yes so I want the scrollview to be in between the title and the buttons at the bottom so it should be Title/ScrollView/Buttons......am i supposed to move the buttons to the bottom in the code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your `ScrolView`

Add `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnBack"`

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnBack"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle">
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you have above and now the scroll view goes behind the title and still is behind the buttons... i just checked to make sure im using proper id's for buttons and title and they are correct

Comment: You can check again.@JoseMoreno

Comment: Yes of course...i think i just realized what you were trying to do.... i think i need to do the margin + the height of the title and the margin + height of the button to make cover all the margin

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much! Sorry i cant upvote, not enough rep but as soon as I do i will return to this!